# Probability spacing between 3 numbers and letters

Tags: php

I want to make probability spacing between numbers and letters like the example above:

**Note that i have two strings each one with 3 letters:**

```
$string1 = "123";
$string2 = "456";

//Result must be:

Line1:  1 2 3
Line2: 4 5 6

--------
$string1 = "456";
$string2 = "891";

//Result must be:

Line1: 46 5
Line2:   8 91

.....
```

How to do this programmatically with PHP and return result like this (using rand function) ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomize the first one, get the position of the values of the first line as a seed and use it on the second string as space. Example: (I just used a bullet instead of a space)

```
// handle first line
$string1 = "123";
// create an array with the characters with spaces
$string1 = array_merge(str_split($string1), array_fill(0, 3, '&bull;'));
shuffle($string1); // shuffle them first
// determine and sace the keys of the non empty characters
$empty_keys = array_keys($string1, '&bull;'); 
$values = array_diff(array_keys($string1), $empty_keys);

$line1 = implode('', $string1);

// second line
$string2 = "456";
$temp = str_split($string2); // create a temporary holder
for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    if(isset($values[$i])) {
        $line2[$i] = '&bull;';
    } else {
        $line2[$i] = array_pop($temp);
    }
}

$line2 = implode('', $line2);

echo $line1 . '<br/>' . $line2;
```

Comment: 1) "I don't know but you can also use" - huh? 2) he doesn't want to shuffle.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath then what do you propose of what he wants then? the OP said might be possible using rand function

Comment: @KarolyHorvath the OP made tons of revisions before this current version of the question, he even stated it must have 6 characters in total, including the gaps `' '` (spaces)

Comment: Hi, first thank you for your suggestion :) but your example don't work, the first string and the second one must be like the example i given on the question :) here spaces are importants :) the first string must fill the spaces of the second string :) thank you another one.

Comment: @user3818090 okay you should have stated that from the beginning could have avoided confusion, including the confused one and downvoted me instead

Comment: Sorry :( i edited it lot of time to get a clear question :) any why this function help a lot :) the idea is this one: using str_shuffle for the first string, and for the second: detecte the position of letter and numbers from the fist one and place space at her place in the second one :)

Comment: @user3818090 check the revision

Comment: And it's not me that downvoted you :) I tried to upvote but don't have 15 reputations :( PLEASE SOMEONE UPVOTE This answer :)

Comment: @Ghost It's always funny if a correct answer get's down voted, but always remember everything will turn good sometimes :D